# I was trying to download the 'punct' from nltk but it says that the connection is refused? What should I do?

Tags: python, installation, download, nltk

*Here below is my code*

```
import nltk
import ssl

try:
    _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
    pass
else:
    ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context

nltk.download('punkt')
```

*Here below is the response*

```
[nltk_data] Error loading punkt: <urlopen error [Errno 61] Connection
[nltk_data]     refused>
```

I tried to use python 3 to download that but it didn't work.  I use Mac.  My location is in China but I use VPN.  I want to know what can I do to install it (my code needs this library).